# Cannot find sin(double), sin(double&), cos(double), cos(double&)

Tags: c++, linker, trigonometry

This is a very simple question which is puzzling me.

I'm getting the following error(s) for one source file but not the other:

```
4  src/Source2.cpp:1466: error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(double&)’
5  src/Source2.cpp:1466: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double)’
6  src/Source2.cpp:1467: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double&)’
7  src/Source2.cpp:1467: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double)’
8  src/Source2.cpp:1468: error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(double)’
9  src/Source2.cpp:1479: error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(double&)’
10 src/Source2.cpp:1479: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double)’
11 src/Source2.cpp:1480: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double&)’
12 src/Source2.cpp:1480: error: no matching function for call to ‘sin(double)’
13 src/Source2.cpp:1481: error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(double)’
```

Which is weird since I have Header1.hpp/Source1.cpp working, but Header2.hpp/Source2.cpp not working. The difference between them is that Source2 is using "doubles" and Source1 is using "floats", but casting gave the same errors as above with 'sin(float)' or 'cos(float)'.

I think I'm linking the math library since the other source (same program) works and doesn't complain.

Any advice is appreciated =)

Thanks in advance!

Code Snippets:

Header1.hpp:

```
4  #include <iostream>
5
6  #include <stdio.h>
7  #include <math.h>
8  #include <ctime>
9
10 #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
11
13 #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
14 #include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Source1.cpp:

```
123   aim[0] = cos(camTheta)*sin(camPhi);
124   aim[1] = sin(camTheta)*sin(camPhi);
125   aim[2] = cos(camPhi);
126 
127   up[0] = cos(camTheta)*sin(camPhi - pih);
128   up[1] = sin(camTheta)*sin(camPhi - pih);
129   up[2] = cos(camPhi - pih);
```

Header2.hpp:

```
4  #include <algorithm>
5  #include <iostream>
6  #include <fstream>
7  #include <sstream>
8  #include <vector>
9  #include <cmath>
. . .
25 #define pih (M_PI/2.0)
26 #define pi M_PI
27 #define pi2 (2.0*M_PI)
```

Source2.cpp:

```
1453   double theta, phi;
1454   double x, y, z;
. . .
1464     node(n,0) = cos(theta)*sin(phi - pih);
1465     node(n,1) = sin(theta)*sin(phi - pih);
1466     node(n,2) = cos(phi - pih);
```

Comment: So does Source2.cpp include either Header1.hpp or Header2.hpp (or anything else)?

Comment: Yes, each includes the respective header on top.
Source2 only includes Header2, similar with Source1

Comment: You should try to be consistent re. `math.h` vs. `cmath`. If you settle for `cmath`, then prepend `std::` to those functions.

Comment: Does Source2 have a `using namespace std`? The Standard doesn't specify whether those functions (in `cmath`, that is) are also in the global namespace or only in `std`.

Comment: Yeah, @pete-becker answered it right.
Thanks guys!

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, I'll try and be consistent. Thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header `<math.h>` puts its names into the global namespace. The header `<cmath>` puts its names into the namespace `std`. (Each is allowed to put names into the other namespace as well). When code uses `<math.h>`, the way to call the sin function is `sin(theta)`. When code uses `<cmath>`, the way to call the sin function is `std::sin(theta)` (unless the code uses the abomination `using namespace std`). In Source2.cpp, the `#include` directive pulls in `<cmath>`, so the file should use the qualified name and not the raw name. Or change the `#include` directive to pull in `<math.h>`, which is what Source1.cpp does.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it!
I didn't know that, thanks =)

It doesn't let me check mark it for 9 minutes, I'll do it after the time limit

Comment: @Yuuta - that's the general pattern: C headers end with `.h`, and the corresponding C++ header starts with `c` and has no extension. The C headers put names into the global namespace (and maybe into `std`), and the C++ headers put names into `std` (and maybe into the global namespace).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the extra explanation.
I still have a lot to learn haha

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lm` for "libm" (m = math) to your linking line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'm linking the math library already.